# Include python script/program in PHP

Tags: php, python

I am new to Python and currently have to write a python program/script to be integrated inside PHP. Basically I have one stand-alone python program that will be executed through CRONTAB that grabs data from a remote device and exports the data to an XML file. I also have to write another python program/script to be include inside PHP to read the XML and echo/print the data onto the screen. So my question is that

1. What is the difference between python program and script? Given my python program, I included #!/usr/bin/env python at the beginning of the file but I still cant execute it using ./scriptName.py
2. How to include and run a python program/script inside the PHP file? Inside the python script, how to output the data using the same manner as echo in PHP? The include part in my PHP is:

   ```
   <td><p><img src="img/today.gif" alt="today" width="180" height="40" /></p>
       <?php include "monthphotos.php"; ?>
       <?php include "todayatcpp/index.php"; ?>
   </td>
   ```

I am new to beginner programmer so some of my questions can be obscure. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can run a python script inside of a PHP script is to use the `exec` call. With that you will be able to capture the output from the python script and be able to use it in PHP.

Comment: Is there any way to "include" the script? Or the only way to do it is to exec the script?

Comment: The only way is to exec the script. Trying to include it would cause PHP to try to parse it as PHP, which wont work.